# Make a json with php

Tags: php, json

My Json:

```
[{"date": "2017-04-27 00:00:00", "type": "meeting", "title": "Başlık", "description": "açıklama", "url": "#"},{"date": "2017-04-27 00:00:00", "type": "meeting", "title": "Başlık", "description": "açıklama", "url": "#"}]
```

ı want this type json with php, help me pls.

Comment: Can you explain, what problem you are getting and what exactly you want from us.

Comment: `print_r(json_decode($your_string, true));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
$arr = array ( 
  array (
    'date' => '2017-04-27 00:00:00',
    'type' => 'meeting',
    'title' => 'Başlık',
    'description' => 'açıklama',
    'url' => '#',
  ),
  array (
    'date' => '2017-04-27 00:00:00',
    'type' => 'meeting',
    'title' => 'Başlık',
    'description' => 'açıklama',
    'url' => '#',
  ),
);
echo json_encode($arr );
```

Comment: ıts working, thank you :)